# Why should not mix IQueryable and IEnumerable queries?

Tags: c#, linq

When doing a query in Linq, it's recommended that you don't combine `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable` parts. Is it just a matter of performance or what?

I want to do some clarifications. some time it's not feasible to do so (like what @Harald Coppoolse explained in his answer. but some time it's feasible but I'm not sure what happens with the performance for example.

Suppose this sudo code:

```
'from e in someIEnumerable
join q in someIQueryable on e.reference equals q.ID'
```

Then what will happen to this query?

Comment: Recommended by who, in what situation? There's probably a scenario where it's easy to show it's a bad idea, but it is by no means some universal truth. If there is trouble it generally comes from unknowingly switching from a LINQ provider (a database, service or anything else) to LINQ to Objects, retrieving much more data from the provider than is necessary because the provider could have filtered/aggregated it itself. On the other hand, depending on the provider that's sometimes the only way to get things done.

Comment: seems it's a problem in running the iqueryable part each time it participates in the whole query. for example when an iqueryable part join with ienumerable part. i think it's ok to mix them in 'where' part when you want to check for containment for example

Comment: The difference is not so much between `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable`, but on the final expression tree, and what provider does what part of the query. Remember, the interfaces are just *interfaces*; they don't dictate the behavior. It is perfectly possible, for example, for a LINQ provider to take an `IEnumerable`, see that it is actually a simple collection and translate this into an efficient query. (Many DB providers actually do this for `IN` style queries.)

Answer (score 1):

To decide whether to continue an IQueryable LINQ statement with an IEnumerable or not it is important to understand the difference between the two.

An object of a class that implements `IEnumerable<...>` is an object that represents a sequence. It holds everything in it to get the first element of the sequence, and once you've got an element you can ask for the next one, if there is a next element.

This enumerating is started explicitly if you use `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` and `IEnumerator.MoveNext()`, or implicitly when using functions like `foreach`, `ToList()`, `ToDictionary()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, `Sum()`, `Count()`, `Any()`, etc. If you investigate the [source code of Enumerable](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs.html), you'll see that deep down they call `GetEnumator()` and `MoveNext()`

Although an object of a class that implements `IQueryable<...>` also represents a sequence, it doesn't have to know how to enumerate this sequence. It holds an `Expression` and a `Provider`. The `Expression` is a very generic form of the data being queried, the `Provider` knows who must execute the query (quite often a database management system) and the language used to communicate with this executor (usually something SQL-like).

Concatenating `IQueryable` objects with Methods that also return `IQueryable`, will only change the `Expression`; the database is not contacted.

When you call `Queryable.GetEnumerator()` to start enumerating the queryable the `Expression` is sent to the `Provider` who will translate this `Expression` into SQL and queries the executor. The returned data is materialized into an IEnumerable sequence. `GetEnumerator()` is called, and the returned enumerator is returned, so you can call `MoveNext()` and `Current` as if you were enumerating an `IEnumerable`.

Because the `Expression` has to be translated into SQL, you can't do everything with an `IQueryable` that you can do with an `IEnumerable`.

The following will work with an `IEnumerable`:

```
double CalculateValueAddedTax(Price p) {...}

IEnumerable<OrderLine> orderLines = ...
decimal totalValueAddedTax = orderLines
    .Where(orderLine => orderLine.HasValueAddedTax)
    .Select(orderLine => CaculateValueAddedTax(orderLine.Price))
    .Sum();
```

The compiler can't detect any problems with the following:

```
IQueryable<OrderLine> orderLines = ...
decimal totalValueAddedTax = orderLines
    .Where(orderLine => orderLine.HasValueAddedTax)
    .Select(orderLine => CaculateValueAddedTax(orderLine.Price))
    .Sum();
```

Although this compiles, you will get a run-time exception, telling you that `CalculateValueAddedTax` can't be translated into SQL. In fact, there are quite a lot of LINQ functions that are not supported by Entity Framework. See [Supported and Unsupported LINQ methods (LINQ to entities)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities)

The proper solution would be to translate your local function into a concatenation of supported LINQ expressions. If you can't do that, you'll have to execute the part of the query before `CalculateValueAddedTax` first, making it a local enumerable object, before you can use it.

```
IQueryable<OrderLine> orderLines = ...
IEnumerable<Price> pricesWithValueAddedTaxes = orderLines
    .Where(orderLine => orderLine.HasValueAddedTax)
    .Select(orderLine => orderLine.Price)
    .ToList();
decimal totalValueAddedTax = pricesWithValueAddedTax
    .Select(price => CaculateValueAddedTax(price))
    .Sum();
```

Although this would work, it would be a waste to fetch all data if you were only planning to use a few of them, for instance if you would use `FirstOrDefault()`

```
IQueryable<Human> queryAmericans = myDbContext.Humans
    .Where(human => human.Country == "USA")
    .OrderByDescending(human => human.Age);
List<Human> americans = queryAmericans.ToList();
var oldestSpecialAmerican = americans
    .Where(american => american.IsSpecial())
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

It would be a waste to transfer all American humans, and only take the first one. Hence the invention of [AsEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.asenumerable?view=netframework-4.8).

```
Price result = orderLines
    .Where(orderLine => orderLine.HasValueAddedTax)
    .Select(orderLine => orderLine.Price)
    .OrderByDescending(price => price.Value)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(price => CaculateValueAddedTax(price))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

It depends a bit on the `Provider`, what `AsEnumerable` will do, but a smart `Provider` will query the data "per page", so that not all millions of queried data are fetched, but only some, let's say 25. If you would use `FirstOrDefault`, then there would be some fetched for nothing, but at least not millions. As soon as you enumerate the 26th element, the next page is fetched. The page size is a compromise between having fetched too much data, and having to execute a query often.

So the main difference between `AsEnumerable` and `AsQueryable` is that an Enumerable will be executed by your local process: every function that you can call can be executed by the Enumerable. `AsQueryable` is executed by an external process. Every function that you call has to be translated into the language that the external process understands, thus limiting the functions you can use in your query.

Compilers can't detect what language the external process uses, and won't complain. If you  use unsupported functions, you'll get an exception.

**Back to your question: should I use AsEnumerable / AsQueryable**

### AsEnumerable

The examples above show that sometimes you'll have to query part of the data to local process before continue LINQ-ing. The smart way to do this is by using AsEnumerable.

One of the slower parts of a database query is the transport of selected data to your local process. So if you decide to use AsEnumerable, try to transfer only the data that you need locally: don't transfer complete `OrderLines` if you only want to process the `Prices`

Furthermore, see if you can change your local function into an IQueryable.

```
IQueryable<decimal> CalculateValueAddedTaxes(this IQueryable<Price> prices)
{
    return prices.Select(price => price.VatPercentage * prive.Value);
}
```

Now the complete query can be executed by the database management system:

```
var result = orderLines
    .Where(orderLine => orderLine.HasValueAddedTax)
    .Select(orderLine => orderLine.Price)
    .OrderByDescending(price => price.Value)
    .CalculateValueAddedTaxes()
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

### AsQueryable

If you have a local enumerable, `AsQueryable` won't suddenly transfer your data to a database. What it does, it creates an `Expression` and a `Provider`. This `Expression` is only the function call to the input data. Just like with any queryable, when you start enumerating, the `Expression` is sent to the `Provider`. This `Provider` will do nothing more than execute the `Expression`, meaning that `GetEnumerator` is called.

**So why should I use AsQueryable?**

In rare occasions, you'll have a local enumerable sequence and you need to call a function that needs an `IQueryable` as input:

```
IQueryable<decimal> CalculateValueAddedTaxes(this IQueryable<Price> prices) {...}

Order newOrder = new Order() {...};      // A local object
newOrder.TotalVAT = newOrder.OrderLines  // A local sequence of OrderLInes
     .AsQueryable()                      // still Local, but now as IQueryable
     .CalculateValueAddedTaxex()         // so you can call this function
     .Sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

**In the context of LinQ to Entities**

`IQueryable` extends `IEnumerable` and is just a query expression. That means it does not resolve data in the Entity data store until a `.ToList()` or a `FirstOrDefault()` for instance.

`IEnumerable` provide `GetEnumerator()` method, allowing to iterate through the **already resolved** collections.

So, you should use `IQueryable` until your Data Access Layer, then, use `IEnumerable` when you already get your data.

Using the proper Interface is a way to not get all the non needed data, and work (for exemple iterate) only on the data you need to work on.

**EDITED based on JonSkeet answer**

Comment: "allowing to iterate throw the **already resolved collection**" - no, LINQ to Objects is still lazy too.

Comment: @JonSkeet I was not aware of that, I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: You might also want to change 'throw' to 'through'

Comment: @Skrface Just as a quick example of an unresolved collection using `IEnumerable`, check out [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Izufj8) fiddle. Fiddle limits the output, but if you were to run this locally, it would look like the collection contained an infinite sequence of random numbers.

Answer (score -1):

I realized that when combining `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable` with join:

1. if the first term is `IEnumerable` and the second one `IQueryable`, then all the query would be `IEnumerable`, the `IQueryable` part first executes and returns the data to the memory then the query go on.
2. but if the first term is `IQueryable` and the second one is `IEnumerable`, an exception will be thrown because the second term could not be translate to `IQueryable`